# Rails spec pass example alone but fail the whole file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, rspec-rails

I have one rails spec file.
When I run: **rspec my_spec.rb**

There were 3 failures. These failures are in the same context.

[image]

But when I run them seperately (Example: **rspec my_spec.rb:231**),
they passed.

Rarely individually test also failed, if that, I restarted docker then it passed again.

[image]

I am not sure what was wrong? 
I tried adding **DatabaseCleaner.clean** and **redis.flushdb** in spec_helper but no lucky.
Any idea can help?

Comment: Could you please add the whole context with failing specs? And the errors which you get

Comment: Please add the example that is failing.

Comment: @All, I would appreciate your help, i found out the issue came from factory object.

Answer (score 0):

Is very difficult to help you without the specs.But based on my own experience, usually this is a problem with hardcoded expects. Like:

`expect(response.id).to eq(1)`

rather then:

`expect(response.id).to eq(object.id)`

When you run your test only it works because of there one entity only. Check this and if it don't help, please provide us more information. Glad to help.

Comment: The issue is related to the girl factory. I highly  appreciate your help!